# Delete using alternate key

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

Since we can update an entity using an [alternate key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932139.aspx):

```
var entity = new Entity("my_entity", "my_alternate_key", "my_value");
entity["my_updated_field"] = "Update";
service.Update(entity);
```

I was expecting to be able to delete the same kind of way:

```
var ref = new EntityReference("my_entity", "my_alternate_key", "my_value");
service.Delete(ref);
```

But [`Delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.delete.aspx) can only take a `Guid`

Is there a way to delete a record using a an alternate key ?

*I mean without retrieving it before*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete by alternate key using the Organization Service. For that you need to have the guid of the record in question (e.g. by retrieving it first).

It is possible to delete using alternate keys via the Web API as shown on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607871.aspx#Anchor_3):

> Any time you need to uniquely identify an entity to retrieve, update,
>   or delete, you can use alternate keys configured for the entity

Comment: Ok that's what I saw too. Hoping that they'll implement this in the .NET SDK on the future.

Answer (score 1):

If someone stumbles over that question like me:
Actually, you **can** delete by alternate key using the Organization Service. No clue if that feature was added in the past 5 years or was available all the time.

```
 var deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest
 {
       Target = new EntityReference("my_entity", "my_alternate_key", "my_value")
 };
 await client.ExecuteAsync(deleteRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [RetrieveMultiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple.aspx) to get the GUIDs that you want to delete, and then call [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.delete.aspx).

Comment: I wanted to avoid retrieving first (mentionned in italic in the question) but that doesn't seem possible indeed